# File system synchronization remotely

Tags: synchronization, filesystems

I have a requirement of synchronizing the file system remotely. I will be storing the content in the form of images in the file system. This storage will be available on cloud. Now how can I synchronize file system on cloud with destination local file system so that it becomes the exact replica and I can access the content locally. My technology stack is Java based. If someone can share any case study or provide any tips/tools, it will be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No case studies here, but take a look at http://jfilesync.sourceforge.net/: it is open source, so you should be able to rip out the actual sync code used by the command line tools and reuse it.