# How to do offsite/cloud file synchronization

Tags: c#, c++, synchronization, cloud

I was curious to find out what are the basics of the file access synchronization for cloud file storage -- pretty much what Microsoft's Skydrive or Dropbox apps do?

Say, how do they deal with a situation when say two or more clients try to connect (read/write) to the same file on the server?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a question for SO, but one potential answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351720/file-system-synchronization-remotely

Comment: @Michael_B: Why would it not be? It's a programming question.

Comment: Very broad question, but start here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api

Comment: @ahmd0 I know there's debate in the community, but my view is that a SO question should have a 'what have i tried' section, and a concrete, solvable question. This is a question that could probably be answered in many ways...each of which could be right.  That being said, I'm interested in the answer, if someone provides it. But it's too much work for me to attempt my own answer.

Comment: @Michael_B: I'd be OK to hear people's take on it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New DropBox Api (Datastore API) have something useful for a real synchronization [support](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore).
It have offline access and automatic conflict resolution.

Comment: Very nice that they added it. It wasn't there when I was asking this question.